# Node.js asynchronous writes to serialport

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-serialport

I have a Node.js application where the following conditions apply:

- 1 SeriaPort object (e.g. for "/dev/ttyUSB0") that I only use for writing data to it.
- A timer that is triggered every x time which writes data to that SerialPort object
- A RestAPI when called also writes data to the same SerialPort object

---

My question is:

Is it a problem that 2 asynchronous processes write to the same object? My gut feeling says yes but I am still a newbie at Node.js and I don't know for sure.

- No. Could someone explain me why? Does the serialport object serialize internally write calls?(I didn't see something like that in their source code)
- Yes. Could someone hint me towards a solution? Do I need to use some kind of locking mechanism? (I am limited though to Node.js 4.x and not sure if I can use await structures)

Comment: what's problem to try 2-3 parallel apps that read, write to same device? if it will work - so everything is cool. if it will not work - use message queue systems: redis mq, rabbit mq and do push requests to queue and in another side write app that takes queue job and works with device.

Comment: @num8er That data written from one app is mingled with data from the other. So app-1 writes 'Hello' and app-2 writes 'World'. I would prefer to see 'HelloWorld' or 'WorldHello' in my serial output rather than 'HelWorllod'.

Comment: Your wish a bit non trivial. So, here is Your solution: `app-1` writes to `app-1.out` file and `app-2` writes to `app-2.out` file. `app-3` reads that 2 files with timing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#usage-basic-cron-usage and concatenate that 2 files and write to device.